# Intermediate theorem on a function of more dimensions

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following question in my textbook:

Let $M>0$ and $\phi :  \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable with the property that $$||\nabla \phi(x)|| \leq M$$

Proof that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^p$ the following holds:

$$ | \phi(x) -\phi(y)| \leq M ||x-y|| $$

Hint: look at the function $g:t \mapsto \phi(x + t(y-x))$

I am able to proof this for a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the use of the intermediate theorem but I don't see how I can apply it to $\phi$. How can I use this theorem to proof this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^p$.

As suggested by the hint provided, $g$ is a function defined from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $g(0)=\phi(x)$ and $g(1)=\phi(y)$. So you can apply the intermediate value theorem to $g$.

The only think that you have to do to get the result, is to compute $g^\prime$ which you can do using the chain rule.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $g(0) =\phi(x)$ and $g(1)= \phi(y)$? And how can I then apply the intermediate value theorem? Because that would be used on t and not on x or y

Comment: You're right. I modify my answer.